# Regex for html tags that are encapsulated by table elements

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am trying to create regular expression that returns number of tables or table array. So far I have

```
  @"<table>^<([a-z]+)([^<]+)*(?:>(.*)<\/\1>|\s+\/>)$</table>"
```

The html can be

```
 <table>
   <p id='p1'></p>
 </table>
 <table>
   <p>abc</p>
 </table>
```

for example if I run following code

```
    string str = "<table><p id='p1'></p></table><table><p>abc</p></table>";
    Regex r = new Regex(@"/<table>^<([a-z]+)([^<]+)*(?:>(.*)<\/\1>|\s+\/>)$</table>/");
    MatchCollection s = r.Matches(str);
    Response.Write(s.Count);
```

Then it should write "2" since there are two tables.

The above regex isn't working as expected. The regex for parsing html seems to be ok, but I am having difficulty in combining the regex for html and regex that encapsulates html (table that encapsulates html elements)

Comment: Look up "non-greedy regex"... And get better (non-HTML) sample to avoid downvotes...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Can you be little more specific? what is non-greedy regex?

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=%22non-greedy+regex%22+msdn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
var nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
```

Comment: Good approaches are not fun :)... Where is hard and painful merging of regular expressions? Building skills in back references? Properly accounting for random whitespaces? Now you just killed entertainment for OP for whole week :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, :), Sorry for the poke fun!

Comment: but I was looking for regex solution. do u have any idea for upvote?

Comment: @user1508643, HTML is not a regular language and Regex cannot parse it correctly. You can try to make sense of a limited subset, but it will never be a robust solution.

Comment: @user1508643 - for educational read on HTML and regex check out top voted [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1) answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ok but can you tell me how can I count <table>anything</table><table>anything</table>. I need to know how many tables are there?